# How to convert \\ into \ in python with regex or replace?

Tags: python, regex, expression

I didn't find out yet how to substitute any text (with re.sub or str.replace) when the text to be inserted is a single backslash ( \ ).

I tried this:

```
import re

cad = 'random\\text'

re.sub(r"\\\\", "\\", cad)
```

but i got:

```
   raise error, v # invalid expression
error: bogus escape (end of line)
```

The pattern seems correct, as I checked on http://pythex.org/ The problem relies on the replacement. 
Any idea?

Comment: you didnt set your second string as a raw string so the pattern that the regex engine reads is just a single backspace which is invalid. ie for regex, `'\\\\\\\\' == r'\\\\'`

Comment: but as @Ethan Bierlein stated, just use str.replace

Comment: `"\\"` = `r"\"`. [*Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character)*](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need to use a regular expression here. You can simply use `str.replace` like this:

```
cad = cad.replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

The above should work.

Answer (score 0):

For the regex to work, you need to use raw strings (`r""` and `r''`) for all strings involving `\`

```
import re
cad = r'random\\text'
newCad = re.sub(r"\\\\", r"\\", cad)
```

Comment: You have to escape backslash with a backslash. So my code *is* replacing two backslashes with one. Look at his original code and you will see that he knows this. All I did was add `r` to his original code.

Comment: I'm running it in python right now and it is replacing two backslashes with one. Run it yourself.

Comment: Okay, but using `re.sub` in this case is still not necessary.